# Compare two very large sorted arrays efficiently

Tags: ruby, arrays, jruby

I need to find an efficient way of find out what is different between two large sorted arrays. In other words, I need to find out **what was added/deleted from one of them based on comparisons with the other**. The sorting is optional, so if you think we can achieve something with no ordering, that is fine with me.

These two arrays are each one million elements long, so **comparing them in memory at once is not feasible.**

The background for this is simple. I am trying to get all new rows from remote legacy SQL (OpenEdge) table that does not have any way of telling what is new. I know this might sound strange, but it is a reality I am working with. So no triggers on data, no timestamps, nothing. This was resolved in another StackOverflow thread so *I am not looking for ways to add this functionality to the remote table*.

I have a copy of this table in my Postgresql local database to help with comparisons. I am doing the comparison over the network and using jRuby with a JDBC driver to inspect remote data. Up to now I tried to load both tables into Ruby arrays and do a standard `array - array`, but this eats up why too much memory (the tables are each a million rows long).

Any other options for me to consider? Any algorithms I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both arrays are already sorted, then you can go through both arrays at the same time and compare the elements using an index per array. If the elements at index i and j are equals, then advance both indexes. If the elements are different, then just advance the index where the element in the array is less than the element in the other array.

Here's the code for this method. Note that it assumes both arrays are sorted and the elements can be compared through `==`, `<` and `>`:

```
def compare_sorted_arrays a1, a2
  i, j = 0, 0
  output = []
  while i < a1.length and j < a2.length do
    if a1[i] == a2[j]
      i += 1
      j += 1
    elsif a1[i] < a2[j]
      output << a1[i]
      i += 1
    else
      output << a2[j]
      j += 1
    end
  end
  i.upto(a1.length-1) do |x|
    output << a1[x]
  end
  j.upto(a2.length-1) do |x|
    output << a2[x]
  end
  output
end
```

And a simple test

```
puts (compare_sorted_arrays([1, 2, 3, 4,], [1, 3, 5, 7])).join(', ')
puts (compare_sorted_arrays([1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4,])).join(', ')
```

Output:

```
2, 4, 5, 7
2, 4, 5, 7
```

Another option may be doing the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) directly in SQL as shown here: [Does the SQL spec provide for a better way to do a exclusive ORing of two sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2188100/1065197)

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(A.id, B.id) AS id
FROM InitialTable A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableToCompareWith B
ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.id IS NULL OR B.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Remember that I don't have the entire array at once. What I am currently doing is comparing 1000 elements from each at once. Maybe I need to clarify my question.

Comment: @n_x_l still, the algorithm should keep working even if you pass slices of the array through the method.

Comment: @n_x_l updated the answer to provide a postgres solution. Not sure if can work since you don't specify if both tables are in the same database server.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work though. The other database is a Progress OpenEdge database, so they are extraordinarily different.

Comment: @n_x_l since you stated you make a copy in your local database, then that may help you to do the comparisons. Anyway, I would try to solve this using an ETL tool like Pentaho.

Comment: Oh yes, but I actually get a copy only once, then I was that as the canonical source from which I decide what was added. This task of getting updates I intended to run frequently, that is why I got a copy to my local database.

Comment: @n_x_l I assume you understand that comparing 2 sets of 1m rows has its performance limitations so you should not fire it too often but at specific times in the day, right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This update would normally run on Sunday evenings, where are customers are sleeping.